# Implementing WorkBadge History for Apex/VisualForce

Tags: apex, visualforce, sobject, record-type

What I would like to accomplish is create a visual force/apex page that show's how many times someone has received a specific work badge on salesforce, such as the "Thank You" badge. It's similar to the "recognition" tab in chatter, but I'd like to show the record for how many times someone has gotten 'x' badge. I'm not too sure how I would display any work badge on visual force. I found a link that describes the objects for WorkBadge and Workthanks, but I'm not sure how to implement them to what I'd like to make. I'm new to all of this and I would appreciate any help on guiding me through this. Thank you!

Links:
http://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_workthanks.htm
http://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_workbadge.htm